# How do i populate a database with table/row definitions that were autogenerated?

Tags: scala, slick

I've run the autogenerator against a database (sqlserver db) and it generated a number of table definitions.

I'm looking to use these definitions to populate a new database - i thought i'd just use `Tables.ddl.create` but i'm seeing a compilation error (`value create is not a member of app.db.Tables.profile.DDL`)

also, once a table is created, what's the canonical pattern for populating it? (the autogenerated code doesn't seem to contain `*` projections - is that intentional?)

---

sample autogenerated table definition:

```
 /** Entity class storing rows of table SampleTable
   *  @param sampletableid Database column SampleTableId DBType(uniqueidentifier), Length(36,false)*/
  case class SampleTableRow(sampletableid: Option[String])

  /** GetResult implicit for fetching SampleTableRow objects using plain SQL queries */
  implicit def GetResultSampleTableRow(implicit e0: GR[Option[String]], e1: GR[Int], e2: GR[Option[java.sql.Clob]], e3: GR[java.sql.Timestamp]): GR[SampleTableRow] = GR{
    prs => import prs._
   SampleTableRow.tupled((<<?[String]))
  }

  /** Table description of table SampleTable. Objects of this class serve as prototypes for rows in queries. */
  class SampleTable(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[SampleTableRow](_tableTag, Some("dbo"), "SampleTable") {
    def * = (sampletableid) <> (SampleTableRow.tupled, SampleTableRow.unapply)
    /** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
    def ? = (sampletableid).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _3.map(_=>SampleTableRow.tupled((_1)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))    
    /** Database column SampleTableId DBType(uniqueidentifier), Length(36,false) */
    val sampletableid: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("SampleTableId", O.Length(36,varying=false))
  }

  /** Collection-like TableQuery object for table SampleTable */
  lazy val SampleTable = new TableQuery(tag => new SampleTable(tag))
```

Comment: I never used the schema generator with an SQL database (only PostgreSQL and MySQL), but as far as I know the projection method should be auto generated.

Comment: it's definitely not there, for any of my 20 or so table definitions

Comment: Could you add one table definition to the question?

Comment: Just use slick methods (insert, delete, filter etc) which will translate into the queries. Or you can write a generic table object, add all necessary methods there and make other tables descend from it.

Comment: @Ashalynd editing auto-generated code by hand is usually a *very bad* idea. is there something about the slick autogenerator or slick in general which, unusually, makes this kind of change a good idea?

Comment: None I know of, you are supposed to define yourself what you need.

Comment: @blueberryfields you do have a projection method `def * = (sampletableid) ...`, also calling create on the TableQuery object works for me as shown by Ashalynd.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a generic Table object you can do with Slick (this assumes you have database:Database in scope):

```
  abstract class genericTable[T <: Table[A] , A] {
    val table: TableQuery[T]

    /**
     *  regenerate the table based on its definition in code
     */
    def create = database.withSession { implicit session =>table.ddl.create }

    /**
     *  drop the table from schema
     */
    def drop = database.withSession { implicit session =>table.ddl.drop }

    /**
     *  insert an entry of the given type
     */
    def insert(entry: A): A = database.withSession { implicit session =>
      table += entry
    }

    /**
     *  insert several entries of the given type
     */
    def insertAll(entries: List[A]) = database.withSession { implicit session =>
       table.insertAll(entries:_*) }

    /*
     *  return all elements from the given table
     */
    def all: List[A] = database.withSession { implicit session =>
      table.list.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
    }
  }
```

and then you can define your concrete query object as:

```
object sampleTable extends genericTable(SampleTable, SampleTableRow) {
    val table = TableQuery[SampleTable]
}
```

and get all the methods you have defined in the base class. That means, from some other place you can make calls like:

```
val allSampleRecords = sampleTable.all
sampleTable.insertAll(List(SampleTableRow(None), SampleTableRow(Some("anEntry"))))
```

because methods all and insertAll are already defined.

If there are some more generic ways of serializing data to tables defined with Slick, I'd be curious to know about them too :)

Comment: please read the question more carefully. the question specifically relates to the autogenerated tables that slick provides - see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/code-generation.html